# How to configure artemis address setting management-message-attribute-size-limit via jmx/web ui?

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis

I have an artemis instance running and would like to set the address setting [`management-message-attribute-size-limit`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html) to a different value than it's default `256`. How can this be achieved via JMX or the web UI?

When reading the settings via `getAddressSettingsAsJSON("<my-address-name>")`  I don't even get this value being returned. I only get:

```
{
    "DLA": "DLQ",
    "expiryAddress": "ExpiryQueue",
    "expiryDelay": -1,
    "minExpiryDelay": -1,
    "maxExpiryDelay": -1,
    "maxDeliveryAttempts": 10,
    "pageCacheMaxSize": 5,
    "maxSizeBytes": -1,
    "pageSizeBytes": 10485760,
    "redeliveryDelay": 0,
    "redeliveryMultiplier": 1.0,
    "maxRedeliveryDelay": 0,
    "redistributionDelay": -1,
    "lastValueQueue": false,
    "sendToDLAOnNoRoute": false,
    "addressFullMessagePolicy": "PAGE",
    "slowConsumerThreshold": -1,
    "slowConsumerThresholdMeasurementUnit": "MESSAGES_PER_SECOND",
    "slowConsumerCheckPeriod": 5,
    "slowConsumerPolicy": "NOTIFY",
    "autoCreateJmsQueues": true,
    "autoDeleteJmsQueues": true,
    "autoCreateJmsTopics": true,
    "autoDeleteJmsTopics": true,
    "autoCreateQueues": true,
    "autoDeleteQueues": false,
    "autoCreateAddresses": true,
    "autoDeleteAddresses": false,
    "configDeleteQueues": "OFF",
    "configDeleteAddresses": "OFF",
    "maxSizeBytesRejectThreshold": -1,
    "defaultLastValueKey": "",
    "defaultNonDestructive": false,
    "defaultExclusiveQueue": false,
    "defaultGroupRebalance": false,
    "defaultGroupRebalancePauseDispatch": false,
    "defaultGroupBuckets": -1,
    "defaultGroupFirstKey": "",
    "defaultMaxConsumers": -1,
    "defaultPurgeOnNoConsumers": false,
    "defaultConsumersBeforeDispatch": 0,
    "defaultDelayBeforeDispatch": -1,
    "defaultQueueRoutingType": "MULTICAST",
    "defaultAddressRoutingType": "MULTICAST",
    "defaultConsumerWindowSize": 1048576,
    "defaultRingSize": -1,
    "autoDeleteCreatedQueues": false,
    "autoDeleteQueuesDelay": 0,
    "autoDeleteQueuesMessageCount": 0,
    "autoDeleteAddressesDelay": 0,
    "redeliveryCollisionAvoidanceFactor": 0.0,
    "retroactiveMessageCount": 0,
    "autoCreateDeadLetterResources": false,
    "deadLetterQueuePrefix": "DLQ.",
    "deadLetterQueueSuffix": "",
    "autoCreateExpiryResources": false,
    "expiryQueuePrefix": "EXP.",
    "expiryQueueSuffix": "",
    "enableMetrics": true
}
```

I'm running artemis 2.31.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't adjust `management-message-attribute-size-limit` via JMX or the web console. You'll need to modify it via `broker.xml`.

This should be resolved implicitly via [ARTEMIS-3932](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3932) in a future version.